# Centos7 - Boots in emergency mode

Tags: linux, centos

After a powercut, my centosOS7 server boots into emergency mode.  `systemctl reboot` and `systemctl default` lands me back at the same point.

I've run the following commands and taken photos of the results:

```
cat /etc/fstab
fdisk -lu
pvs
vgs
lvs
```

[image: fstab]

[image: fdisk]

[image: pvs-vgs-lvs]

I have no clue about linux, is the problem obvious?

`journalctl -xb` gives a large amount of data, I've taken photos of the red lines:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

Comment: There are a lot of references to this on the web https://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=15594 being one example.

Answer (score 0):

Your Megento service is broken and causing a failure to boot, I would suggest disable the service from starting and then boot your system to debug the system.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the system expects a LV named `home` to also exist in the `centos_magento` VG, but it does not seem to be present.

As a workaround to get the system to boot fully, you might edit `/etc/fstab` to comment out the line referring to `/home`. With that line commented out, the system should get past this point, but obviously the home directories of any normal user accounts would be missing, as `/home` would just be an empty directory on the root filesystem that is normally used to mount the `home` LV.

Since there are no messages about missing LVM PVs, it seems like the LV may have been deleted with `lvremove /dev/mapper/centos_magento-home` or `lvremove /dev/centos_magento/home` (new and old LVM device name syntax, respectively).

If you need to undo the LV remove operation, `/etc/lvm/archive` should contain an archive of previous VG configurations. You might be able to use `vgcfgrestore` to go back to the previous version of the VG configuration for the `centos_magento` VG.

If the `issue_discards` option in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` was not enabled while the LV was deleted, the data should be still there on the physical disk surface unless it was overwritten, and just restoring the previous version of the VG configuration might completely fix the problem and allow you to uncomment the `/home` filesystem line in `/etc/fstab` again.

Answer (score 0):

I found some issues in `/var/log/boot.log` that pointed me to an issue with the home directory.

Unlike `/` and `swap`, `/home` was missing for me when I looked at `lvs`, and home was not mounted when I looked at `mount`.

Executing the `vgchange -ay` command works for me. `/home` was mounted after executing the `vgchange -ay` command.

Answer (score 0):

1. boot from an iso with same major release version, latest minor if possible.
2. go into rescue mode, then go straight to shell
3. lvscan to get path to logical volumes
4. lvchange -ay for each found logical volumes
5. fsck -y for each of the found logical volumes